# How do I install required gcc and libc6-dev files on 20.04?

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc

I am trying to build software from source (specifically, Asymptote 2.66).
This worked fine on Ubuntu 18.04.

But a number of the files the make file needs, such as:

- byteswap-16.h and libio.h in /usr/include/x86-64-linux-gnu/bits/
- limits.h in /usr/lib/gcc/x86-64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed

are simply not present in Ubuntu 20.04. Well, not present in the expected locations. They *can* be found in /snap/gnome-3-34-1804.

Every bit of help online says to install `build-essentials`, `libc6-dev`, and `linux-libc-dev`.

But all of these are installed. Other than manually copying needed files one by one, is there a way to get all the necessary files to build from source?

Comment: To answer the most likely questions: 1. I need the most recent Asymptote for certain new features. 2. Yes, there are .deb installers. But the dependencies break my system. In particular, libgsl25 is a dependency and Ubuntu 20.04 has libgsl23. I can't upgrade this library without losing Python, Jupyter, Sage, and other key programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first - the Asymptote 2.62 is contained in the [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/asymptote), so you can start getting its build-dependencies by enabling source code repositories in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep asymptote
```

And then compile the source code:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/archive/2.66.tar.gz
tar -xf 2.66.tar.gz
cd asymptote-2.66
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and then run the application with `asy` command.

Comment: Awesome -- that's a cool trick that I was completely unaware of. Now I feel stupid for past instances trying to build, and discovering one by one what dependencies were missing!

Comment: The only thing I did differently was to build from their GitHub source, and do `make all` instead of `make` since that's what their Git instructions said to do. It still failed on the first try but it turned out I just had to rm the existing git repository, re-clone, and start over.